# Spark running filters on db rather than running on spark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As I am a newbie to Spark maybe i am missing out on something here.

I am using PySpark to get the dataframe from mongo and doing some filtering . 
when i am running that on sayaround 5000 records everything is fine , but when i am runnign the same thing with say around 1,70,000 records instead of filtering the records on dataframe it is running the filtering on mongodb which is making it too slow.

Am I missing something here , may be some configuration.

```
dataframe = df1.where(col("") != '')
                            .filter((col("")
                            .isin(df2["id"))
                            & (col("create_date") >= lit(start_date))
                            & (col("create_date") <= lit(end_date)))
```

i have two dataframes where the second dataframe is iterated for 13k times to get id of each record and match it with the first dataframe(df1) so i can see the queries being fired in mongdb logs ...

Please help.

Comment: How do you know the filtering is working on mongo? It does not make sense.

Comment: because i can see it in mongodb logs

Comment: @Lamanus i have 2 dataframes where the second dataframe is iterated for 13k times to get id of each record and match it with the first dataframe(df1) so i can see the queries being fired in mongdb logs ...

Comment: Your filter is.... :( you have to find the way to join or compare in the other way not to use the dataframe with column function.

Answer (score 0):

Solved ...

I did not create indexes in MongoDB collections, because of which spark was posting queries and was not able to cache.